# Mockito fails to verify multiple invocations of methods from org.slf4j.Logger

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, mockito, powermock

**I have a method that contains 2 conditions. In each condition the Logger.error method is invoked. The first test, that verifies the invocation of that method, succeeds, but any other test fails with**

> Wanted but not invoked...Actually, there were zero interactions with
>   this mock.

**Does anyone know why this happens?**

Below, I provided an example class and a unit test that will generate the issue:

```
package packageName;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class X {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(X.class);

    public void execute(boolean handle1stCase) {
        if (handle1stCase) {
            LOGGER.error("rumpampam");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("latida");
        }
    }
}
```

The test:

```
package packageName;

import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LoggerFactory.class})
public class XTest {

    @Mock
    private Logger loggerMock;

    private X x;

    @Before
    public void construct() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(loggerMock);

        x = new X();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenFirstCaseErrorLogged() throws Exception {
        x.execute(true);
        verify(loggerMock, times(1)).error("rumpampam");
    }

    @Test
    public void whenSecondCaseErrorLogged() throws Exception {
        x.execute(false);
        verify(loggerMock, times(1)).error("latida");
    }
}
```

The outcome:

> Wanted but not invoked: loggerMock.error("latida");
>   -> at packageName.XTest.whenSecondCaseErrorLogged(XTest.java:51)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

**EDIT:**
I gave my short answer of why the every test except the 1st was failing in a [comment of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196591/521754).

**MY SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM**:
In the test provide a:

```
public static Logger loggerMockStatic;
```

Than create only one instance for all the tests and provide it in the static variable, and use the static loggerMockStatic from than on. So you would have:

```
    ...  
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    if (loggerMockStatic == null) {
        loggerMockStatic = loggerMock;
    }

    mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
    //when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(loggerMock);
    when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(loggerMockStatic);
    ...
```

and use loggerMockStatic in the verify methods instead of loggerMock.

**SOME THOUGHTS REGARDING APPROACH**:
For me this is good because
1. it doesn't break design (if you considered that the needed variable should have been a constant, than it will stay this way).
2. its only 4 lines added in the test that will allow you to test the constant (in this case logger) behavior. Not much polluting and test case is still clear.

The "delete final and provide setter" approach as I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20198872/521754) opens the system to vulnerabilities. There is no need for someone to set the logger to the class, and I would always like the system to be as opened as needed. Providing a setter only for the need of a test is not desired. The test should work for the implementation, not the other way around.

Specifically on testing the logging, I don't consider that logging should be tested in general (most of the) cases. Logging should be an aspect of the application. And when you have other outputs to test for a certain path, than those outputs should be tested. But in this case (and maybe others) where there is no other output for a certain path, like logging and returning on a certain condition, testing the log (according to me) is needed. I want to always know that the log message will remain being logged even if someone changes the condition. If there was no log, and if someone changes the condition the wrong way there will be no way of knowing that the mistake resides in this piece of code (except maybe with debugging).

I was discussing with some colleagues that having a separate class for doing the logging would do the trick. That way the constant is isolated in another class, and you will be able to check the behavior with only Mockito. They made a further remark that this way if you would wanted to send the log to an email it would be easier to change.
First of all, I consider this a premature modularization IF you are not aiming in near future to switch between logging ways.
Secondly, using only Mockito + having another class and + 3 lines of code VS my one line of code (logger.error(...)) + using PowerMockito, I would again use the later. Adding additional dependencies during testing will not make you production code slower and bulkier. Perhaps when considering continues integration and that testing is also as important as other phases, you might say that this will make the process slower and bulkier while testing, but I would sacrifice that - it seems not too big of deal to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why this is not working:

Field in class X is static and final which allows to set this only the first time class is loaded. This is dangerous because of what I wrote in my first answer. In your case you are lucky and this is not happening but...

Junit executes your test case in following order:
construct()
whenFirstCaseErrorLogged()
construct()
whenSecondCaseErrorLogged()

Now lets say that after first call to construct() XTest's field loggerMock is pointing to object which resides at the address 0001. This object is then used by LoggerFactory to initialize LOGGER field of x object. x.error is then called from whenFirstCaseErrorLogged() and that works finde because both loggerMock and X::Logger are pointing at the same object.

Now we get to the second construct(). Your loggerMock is reinitialized and now it points to a different object let assume that is stored in memory at the address 0002. This is a new object different from the previously created. Now because your X::LOGGER is static final it won't be reinitialized thus it still points at the object stored at the address 0001. When you will try to verify methods invoked on loggerMock you will get error because nothing was executed on that object instead error method of your previous object was called.

And here are some thoughts from me. Maybe they will appear helpful.
I think in future you should reconsider using static twice. Why do you want to make something  constant when it is not constant ? Will your reference variable have the same value after you will run for the second time ? Of course it can happen but it is very unlikely. Can static final prevent you from changing the state of the object  ? Of course not they will only prevent you from reassigning LOGGER to a different instance. You mentioned in your previous comment that you don't want a user of your code to provide null reference for your LOGGER. That is ok but you can prevent that by throwing an exception when one is provided or using a different null handling mechanism.

A lot has been said about using static keyword. Some consider it as pure evil some don't and some still love singletons :)

No matter what you think you have to know that static is no good for testing and threading.
I use static final when something is static like PI, or euler number but I don't use static final for objects that have mutable state. I use static methods for utility classes that don't store state but just do some processing ( parsing, counting etc.) and return the result imediatelly. A good example is a math function like power.

I think that will be useful ;)

Comment: "In your case you are lucky and this is not happening but..." Regarding the luck, this is not true. I explained exactly why in comment of your other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20196591/521754 I would suggest in future not to write multiple answers, but to edit your old ones with a comment that it was edited.

Comment: "Why do you want to make something constant when it is not constant ?" The logger is not a constant?! I might be wrong but, it should not change in runtime. Isn't that the definition of a constant in java?! :) "Can static final prevent you from changing the state of the object ?" what state will you change in the logger I am just curious :) (check org.slf4j.Logger interface and see what methods it has ;) )

Comment: There was no need for involving memory addresses in your answer :) this would have sufficed: "because your X::LOGGER is static final it won't be reinitialized" ;) Never the less, I am going to accept your answer because the 2 paragraphs that start with "Now lets say..." are the same spin of the comment I gave you in your previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20196591/521754 (and I can see you deserve a boost :) ). Thanks for your effort Luke! I will provide a concrete way of how I handled the situation for anyone interested.

Comment: I'm glad we are on the same page in terms of the reason why your code is not giving the expected result. 
As you mentioned org.slf4j.Logger is an interface so you can't change it's state but a class that implements it can store logged messages in a vector field or sth and this is the state I was reffering to. The aim of my comment about using final static with class' field was to show that in the end it doesn't buy you anything ( you can guard against null's in a different way) instead it introduces complication to tests ( You created this issue on SO didn't you ;))

Comment: look at the last edit I made. I hope you would agree that it is, after all, easily solvable (=> no need to change the design). Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Your logger is static thus it's loaded when your class is loaded not when object is initialized. You have no guaratee that your mock will be ready on time, sometimes it might work sometimes not.

Comment: In that case, the first test should sometimes fail. But this is not the case!

Comment: Because you are lucky, your first test is always executed first :)

Comment: I hope this kind of happiness follows me :) but 1st test case failing never occurred. And be my guest :) try it 1000 times and you won't get it to fail. Here is why (had no time to reply). In the 1st test, powermockito instructs the static getLogger method to give back loggerMock' and the 1st test will always succeed. My assumption was that the classes get reloaded, so that when in the 2nd test powermockito instructed getLogger method to give back loggerMock'', the 2nd test will succeed. But the 2nd test works with loggerMock' instead. This is why every other test fails. My solution in an edit

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to class `X` to allow the logger to be set, and remove the `final` from it.  Then do something like this in the test.

```
@Mock private Logger mockLogger;
private X toTest = new X();

...
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    toTest.setLogger(mockLogger);
}

@Test
public void logsRumpampamForFirstCall() throws Exception {
    toTest.execute(true);
    verify(mockLogger).error("rumpampam");
}

@Test
public void logsLatidaForOtherCalls() throws Exception {
    toTest.execute(false);
    verify(mockLogger).error("latida");
}
```

Comment: This will make the tests work probably. Unfortunately, I would never try to change the design of the system just to please a test. The LOGGER variable is intentionally a constant (so that others are unable to change it throughout the application).

Comment: That seems an odd choice to me.  This change would make the code more testable.  Code that is more testable is less subject to bugs.  Indeed, ease of testing is a big part of code maintainability.

Comment: @David Wallace is right, but in this situation we can tests without changing system :)

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes code should be testable, but I can't imagine not using constants because I would wanna test the code. This is why frameworks like PowerMockito were invented. MariuszS, not "can" but "must". Otherwise you are opening the system to vulnerabilities. Anyway, I still don't get why mockStatic and verify doesn't do the trick properly :(

Comment: I'm not saying "don't use constants".  I'm saying "don't use them in cases like this".  Writing testable code is a discipline, and with time you'll reap the benefits of it.  Or more likely, the _next_ person to work with this code will reap the benefits.  PowerMock exists as a crutch for those who have not yet learnt this discipline.

Comment: @DavidWallace , tell me, what will happen, if a developer uses that setter method to provide a null reference for the logger? Or maybe provide a different logger in there? You are not seeing a problem there!? Ok...

Comment: Well, I'd have it package-private for a start.  You don't intend it to be part of the API.  But if you have developers in your team who make changes such as that, you've got bigger problems than this particular class.